# Trying to get property 'regular_price' of non-object in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, relational-database, laravel-5.5

I am trying to get the values from other table but i am getting this error
My Model loo like this:

```
class PageList extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'page_master';

    protected $fillable = ['business_id', 'page_url', 'page_name'];

    public function particulars()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Sale','id');
    }
}
```

and my blade template is:

```
<p>{{$value->particulars->regular_price}}</p>
```

I want to get value from page_particulars table and the value is regular_price but i am getting error of trying to get property of non-object.
Where i am doing wrong? 
Any help will be highly appreciated!

```
            public function pageListHere()
{
    $list = PageList::all();
    return view('page-list',compact('list'));
}
```

Comment: `$value` is an array, not a eloquent model (possibly)

Comment: so i can modify to array so my solution can be solved!

Comment: Can you upload what `dd($value)` outputs?

Comment: Also the part where you query the result

Comment: it shows me:   object(App\PageList)#148 (26) { ["table":protected]=> string(11) "page_master" ["fillable":protected]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(11) "business_id" [1]=> string(8) "page_url" [2]=> string(9) "page_name" } ["connection":protected]=> string(5) "mysql" ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(2) "id" ["keyType":protected]=> string(3) "int" ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) ["with":protected]=> array(0) { } ["withCount":protected]=> array(0) { } ["perPage":protected]=> int(15) ["exists"]=> bool(true) ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=> bool(false) ["attributes":protected]=> array(7) { ["id"]=> int(1)

Comment: i added my controller method in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `optional()` helper method

```
<p>{{optional($value->particulars)->regular_price}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You `compact('list')` not `compact($list)` which will not pass the collection result you are expecting, but just a string.

Next to that 
`public function particulars()` seems not to return an object for this `$value` which. So the result might be `null`